# ASP Validar Checkbox en GridView (campo bit SQLtrue/false) en C#

Tags: asp.net

Tengo un `GridView` con la columna editar, pero cuando quiero actualizar una fila, no toma los cambios asignados, lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario haga click en el `CheckBox` ese campo pase a true en mi base de datos.

Este es mi codigo

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1 align="center" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridview1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gridview1_RowEditing1" OnRowUpdating="gridview1_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
             <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="cliente" HeaderText="cliente" SortExpression="cliente" Visible="False" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cliente">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="descripción de tarea" HeaderText="descripción de tarea" SortExpression="descripción de tarea" Visible="False" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descripción de tarea">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[descripción de tarea]") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[descripción de tarea]") %>'></asp:Label>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="estado de tareas" HeaderText="Estado de tareas" SortExpression="estado de tareas" Visible="False" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="estado de tareas">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("[estado de tareas]") %>' />
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("[estado de tareas]") %>' />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="fecha de ejecución" HeaderText="fecha de ejecución" SortExpression="fecha de ejecución" Visible="False" />
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="fecha de ejecución">
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="Date">fecha de Ejecución Tarea</asp:TextBox>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Date">fecha de Ejecución Tarea</asp:TextBox>
                     </ItemTemplate>

                 </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Proyectocliente%>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [vista_estado_tarea]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE vista_estado_tarea SET cliente = @cliente, [Descripción de tarea] = @Descripcion_de_tarea, [Estado de tareas] = @Estado_de_tarea, [Fecha de ejecución] = @Fecha_de_ejecucion WHERE ([Estado de tareas] = @Estado_de_tarea)">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="cliente" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="descripcion_de_tarea" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Estado_de_tarea" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Fecha_de_ejecucion" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Por favor agrega tu codigo para que sea mas facil entender tu pregunta.

Comment: ahí edite mi pregunta con parte del codigo, soy nuevo en el foro y en programacion, muchas gracias

Comment: Me encuentro en la misma situación, si aún te funciona más tarde te la comparto. Saludos!